# How to have a ModelForm with a dynamic amount of related objects?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Here is how my models are setup:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    modelB = models.ForeignKey('ModelB', related_name='modelB')
    # more fields here

class ModelB(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # more fields here
```

The user field in both classes are just so that both of these can be queried by the same user later on.

I have a ModelForm of ModelB and I would like to have the users be able to fill out a ModelB ModelForm with a dynamic number of ModelA instances. I would like ModelB's form to start out with 1 instance of ModelA to fill out and then the user should be able to add more ModelA's to ModelB's form.

I'm stuck on this as a personal project and would really like to move forward. Thanks for any help!

Edit 1: I know that I will most likely need to do some work by overloading ModelForms `def __init__`, but that is about as far as I have gotten. Also I am using ClassBasedGeneric Views (CreateView to get the add working and an EditView later on), but I am willing to move away from that if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require [django inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

In view:

```
f_set = inlineformset_factory(ModelB, ModelA, extra=1)
```

In template lets suppose you are rendering form_set in a `div` whose id is `one_to_many`:

```
<form>
   <div id="one_to_many">
       {{f_set.as_table}}
   </div>
</form>

#This will render some thing like this
<form>
    <div id="one_to_many">
        <table>
            <tr>
               <th>
                   <label for="id_form-0-field_name">Field Name:</label>
               </th>
               <td>
                  <input id="id_form-0-field_name" type="text" name="form-0-field_name" value="" maxlength="100" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="form-0-id" value="1" id="id_form-0-id" />  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Add More Field" id="add_more">
    </div>
</form>
```

Now the `jquery` part to add field dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add_more').click(function(){
            var tbl = $('#one_to_many').children('table');
            var last_id = parseInt(tbl.find('input[type=hidden]').last().val());
            var next_id = last_id + 1;
            htm = '<tr><th><label for="id_form-'+last_id+'-field_name">Field Name:</label></th><td><input id="id_form-'+last_id+'-field_name" type="text" name="form-'+last_id+'-field_name" value="" maxlength="100" /><input type="hidden" name="form-'+last_id+'-id" value="'+next_id+'" id="id_form-'+last_id+'-id" /></td></tr>'
            tbl.find('tr').last().after(htm);

        });    
    });
```

You can test this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dq4gR/). Note this will only work if you render your form `as_table`

Comment: Will this allow me to add more of modelA's on the fly?

Comment: No you have to do that manually using jquery. I am updating my answer to add a snippet how you can do that.

Comment: I think I can probably figure out the jQuery part, but I won't complain if you do add another snippet. I am worried about the server side validation of adding those fields on the fly.

Comment: Another approach would be to display `related field` as text field. And ask user to input values separated by comma. And at backend split the string with comma and then save one by one (or bulk create) to related model.

Comment: I like this implementation better than the csv value. I was going to go with that, but I'd rather let django do more work than me :)